# Bazaar - Creating a post push hook that only runs if a specified folder has changed

Tags: python, hook, bazaar

I have recently started a new job and have undertaken a project to implement some proper source control and continuous integration as the first few steps to automating our local build and testing process.

We have decided to use a mixture of Bazaar (SCM) / Jenkins (For CI) / Nant (heavy lifting work).

What I am having trouble with is figuring out how to create a hook that will check if changes on a specific folder (not a branch) within the repository has occurred. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

To put this in context:
Our repository structure includes a folder for our source code and a folder for our numbered database scripts. At the moment when we check in code we also get a database build/update due to the hook which is undesireable.